# Pegar noticias de um site especifico

Tags: android, scraping

No momento estou procurando uma solução para implementar um modulo no meu *App* para pegar noticias de um site especifico e mostrar na tela do modulo de notícias.

Alguém pode me indicar um caminho?

Answer (score 11):

O nome deste tipo de prática é *page scraping*, uma variação de *[screen scraping](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_scraping)*. De acordo com a página da Wikipedia,

> [..] uma técnica na qual um programa de computador extrai dados da
>   saída de vídeo de um outro programa. [...] O elemento-chave que
>   distingue o screen scraping do *parsing* habitual é que a saída que
>   está sendo capturada foi destinada a ser vista por um utilizador
>   humano , em vez de servir de input para um outro programa [...]
>   Existem uma série de sinônimos, incluindo: web scraping, page
>   scraping, web page wrapping e HTML scraping (específicos para
>   webpages).

O exemplo abaixo, para Android, demonstra este comportamento:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88690").get();
    String question = document.select("#question .post-text p").first().text();
    System.out.println(question);
}
```

O resultado final é a extração do título da sua pergunta, 'Pegar noticias de um site especifico!'.

Fontes:
[Screen scraping (Wikipedia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_scraping)
[What is the fastest way to scrape HTML webpage in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android)

Comment: Uhnn. Compreendo. Vou tentar implementar e volto para compartilhar o resultado final! Fico grato pela ajuda, amigo!

Comment: @RodolfoAbrantes É um prazer ajudar, e espero que funcione!